# crontab does not execute python script

Tags: linux, python-3.x, selenium, cron, raspbian

I am facing an issue of crontab does not run the python script in Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch) installed on a Raspberry Pi3. I have done lots of research on this topic e.g. by following the troubleshooting guide in https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working/24527#24527 , but none of them solved my issue.

The python script that I want to run is located in

```
/home/pi/Documents/Fork_BookManager.py
```

I have made sure that anyone can execute, read and change content to the above file.

I can run this file through terminal by writing

```
usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/Fork_BookManager.py
```

I know the file is running, because the `Fork_BookManager.py` is using selenium to open a web browser, and I see this web browser being opened. There is no error observed when running the `Fork_BookManager.py` file from terminal.

In terminal executed

```
crontab -e
```

Using nano as editor, I first verified that crontab acutally worked by

```
* * * * * env > /home/pi/Documents/env.output
```

After a minute there is a env.output file in `Documents` folder with below parameters.

```
LANGUAGE=da_DK.UTF-8
HOME=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=da_DK.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
LC_ALL=da_DK.UTF-8
PWD=/home/pi
```

I noticed that the path from crontab is different from the path when env is called from terminal as I will have the below path if I call env from terminal
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

So I know that crontab -e was working since I otherwise would not have got the env.output file created in Documents folder. I proceed by calling `crontab -e` from terminal and copied the path from env into the crontab like below

```
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/Fork_BookManager.py
```

Saved the script and waited. Nothing happend.

To summerize I have:

1. Made sure that the `Fork_BookManager.py` is executable
2. Verified that crontab is working
3. Updated path from env into the crontab script

which are three largest cause of experiencing difficulties in making crontab to work according to this guide 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working/24527#24527

Still it is not working. What have I missed? Is there a better practice to achieve what I want, namely to execute the python script once a minute without doing it directly from the python script itself such as a while loop with a `time.sleep(60)`

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

I even tried to expand the path in crontab script by

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/bin:/home/pi/Documents
```

in an attempt to specify in which folder the python3 and `Fork_BookManager.py` is located. Still no luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I don't agree that this question is off-topic. This topic is related to programming the crontab and understanding why it is not working when running python script when it is verified that it works in doing other tasks such as calling the env command. The root cause of this problem might help further improvement of crontab.

Comment: Did you check your `syslog`?